# Display very large data on C1FlexPivotPage

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pivot-table, report, componentone

[Example of C1FlexPivotPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDsMN.png)
I have a very large dataset (4 million rows) which is extracted through a SQL query. I need to show data in a grid, which is part of C1FlexPivotPage, but it takes so long to calculate and display results. This data needs to be custom formatted like pivot tables, filters, and aggregate functions.

So my question is, what is the best practice for speeding up the process of creating these custom reports, such as the Excel pivot table part, which immediately updates the grid view?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Well, but of a side topic but does the user actually need to see 4 million rows?  All good retrieving 4 million rows but can’t imagine many people sifting though that much data to find the info they need.  Is it possible to display some form of summary?

Comment: No user actually doesn't need to see raw data; all that a user needs is to make reports based on that data. This data comes from some type of warehouse database, which is generally used for analytics. My problem is how to optimize the performance of making reports. If someone is experienced with manipulation of this third-party component, I would appreciate help.

Comment: The use of C1FlexPivotPage does kind of suggest a UI to me.  Wouldn't it be better to do as much of the data processing and manipulation as close as possible to the data store?  That way you're only loading your UI with a pre-prepared summary.  Or perhaps maybe implement data retrieval via chucks or via background threads or  a combo even?

Comment: Yes, data is extracted via background threads, but raw data must come to the UI and the user needs to use C1FlexPivotPage to process them to make reports.